# Ошибка связанная с обращением к DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
Ошибка 1: Наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод для
"Dexter.Database1DataSet2TableAdapters.Table1TableAdapter.Insert(int,
string, string, string, int?, int?)" имеет несколько недопустимых
аргументов
```

---

```
Ошибка 2: Аргумент "5": преобразование типа из "string" в "int?"
невозможно
```

---

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 Sell = new Form3();
    Form2 ysl = new Form2();

    n = Sell.dataGridView1.RowCount;
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        label14.Text = ysl.dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[n].Value.ToString(); // = sum;
    sum = label14.Text;

    // Ошибочка тут
    // Sell.table1TableAdapter.Insert(n + 1, textBox4.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, label14.Text);// textBox.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("Операция выполнена успешна");
}
```

Comment: В последние два столбца записываются данные в виде цифр.  Из textBox2.Text, label14.Text беру данные. Помогите исправить.

Comment: В тексте ошибки же все сказано, что не ясно?

Comment: @МстиславПавлов нужна помощь, а конкретней как грамотно записать данные из textBox2.Text, label14.Text в виде String в данной конструкции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы передаете неправильные параметры. У вас метод принимает:

```
(int, string, string, string, int?, int?)
```

А вы передаете:

```
(int, string, string, string, string, string)
```

Конвертировать строку в инт так:

```
int x = Int32.Parse(textBox.Text);
```

А еще лучше так:

```
int x = 0;
Int32.TryParse(textBox.Text, out x);
```